# Changing or moving boot/efi partition to another place on same device

Tags: grub, boot-loader

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 and turns out that I underestimated amount of storage needed for root partition. The problem is that sda3 which I want to resize is trapped between sda2 and boot/efi partition and I'm not sure if that's safe to just move/resize sda4 and if moving it will destroy my system.

[image]